# Unity Launch Mode choice

Tags: 12.04, unity

You know, when to install a fresh ubuntu 12.04 and there a dash with unity launch mode, which do you have to a hide, or nope, right? anyone know how to command this for intelligent like a docky, that i want one, but i find that unity 2D do have one, but why not unity 3d have nothing?

Comment: this might help you: http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2012/04/enable-dodge-unity-launcher-ubuntu-12-04 ; I would advise you to read this before installing from a PPA: http://askubuntu.com/questions/35629/are-ppas-safe-to-add-to-my-system-and-what-are-some-red-flags-to-watch-out

Answer (score 0):

I think that this is what you are looking for ?

[image]

[image]